# Bottle REST API generates different results after page reloading

Tags: python, rest, fortran, bottle

I just built my first `REST API` service, but it behaved weirdly... When this `REST API` is called, it does some calculation and returns the results. However, in my setup, without restarting the `REST` server, only the first time submission's result is correct. Results keep declining since the second submission. Has anyone had this issue before?

#### host

```
all_dic = {"APPRAT":APPRAT, "APPNUM":APPNUM, "APSPAC":APSPAC, "KOC":KOC, "METHAF":METHAF, "WETTED":WETTED,
           "METHOD":METHOD, "AIRFLG":AIRFLG, "YLOCEN":YLOCEN, "GRNFLG":GRNFLG, "GRSIZE":GRSIZE,
           "ORCFLG":ORCFLG, "INCORP":INCORP, "SOL":SOL, "METHAP":METHAP, "HYDHAP":HYDHAP, "FOTHAP":FOTHAP}

data = json.dumps(all_dic)
url='http://localhost:7777/myroute/' 
http_headers = {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'}
response = urlfetch.fetch(url=url, payload=data, method=urlfetch.POST, headers=http_headers)   
self.data_a= json.loads(response.content)["ff"]
```

#### REST Server

```
from bottle import route, run, post, request
import json

@post('/myroute/') 
def myroute():
    APPRAT = request.json["APPRAT"]
    APPNUM = request.json["APPNUM"]
    APSPAC = request.json["APSPAC"]
    KOC = request.json["KOC"]
    METHAF = request.json["METHAF"]
    WETTED = request.json["WETTED"]
    METHOD = request.json["METHOD"]
    AIRFLG = request.json["AIRFLG"]
    YLOCEN = request.json["YLOCEN"]
    GRNFLG = request.json["GRNFLG"]
    GRSIZE = request.json["GRSIZE"]
    ORCFLG = request.json["ORCFLG"]
    INCORP = request.json["INCORP"]
    SOL = request.json["SOL"]
    METHAP = request.json["METHAP"]
    HYDHAP = request.json["HYDHAP"]
    FOTHAP = request.json["FOTHAP"]

    import geneec
    ff=geneec.geneec2(APPRAT,APPNUM,APSPAC,KOC,METHAF,WETTED,METHOD,AIRFLG,YLOCEN,GRNFLG,GRSIZE,ORCFLG,INCORP,SOL,METHAP,HYDHAP,FOTHAP)
    print all the inputs
    print ff
    return json.dumps({'ff':ff})

run(host='localhost', port=7777, debug=True)
```

Where geneec is a `FORTRAN` program copiled into a Python module (geneec.pyd) using `f2py`. I have tested this mudule in a pure Python environment locally and it works fine (results will not be changed after multiple submissions.)
So can anyone give me some suggestions on this issue? Thanks!

### Update

Below are the results print on the server end. What I have seen is the same set of inputs generated different outputs

```
{'GRSIZE': 'a', 'APSPAC': '6', 'INCORP': 0, 'ORCFLG': 'a', 'KOC': '2', 'METHAP': '6', 'SOL': '3', 'YLOCEN': '12', 'FOTHAP'
 'AIRFLG': 'a', 'APPRAT': '4', 'METHOD': 'a', 'WETTED': 'Yes'}
(576.0662841796875, 530.255615234375, 331.788330078125, 153.9146728515625, 104.5523681640625, 'AERL_A', 8.471641540527344,
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Dec/2013 23:41:43] "POST /myroute/ HTTP/1.1" 200 150
{'GRSIZE': 'a', 'APSPAC': '6', 'INCORP': 0, 'ORCFLG': 'a', 'KOC': '2', 'METHAP': '6', 'SOL': '3', 'YLOCEN': '12', 'FOTHAP'
 'AIRFLG': 'a', 'APPRAT': '4', 'METHOD': 'a', 'WETTED': 'Yes'}
(546.4204711914062, 480.0862731933594, 245.5520477294922, 98.00833892822266, 65.50333404541016, 'AERL_A', 8.47164154052734
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Dec/2013 23:41:52] "POST /myroute/ HTTP/1.1" 200 152
{'GRSIZE': 'a', 'APSPAC': '6', 'INCORP': 0, 'ORCFLG': 'a', 'KOC': '2', 'METHAP': '6', 'SOL': '3', 'YLOCEN': '12', 'FOTHAP'
 'AIRFLG': 'a', 'APPRAT': '4', 'METHOD': 'a', 'WETTED': 'Yes'}
(535.4012451171875, 458.6314392089844, 213.1800079345703, 81.3574447631836, 54.282127380371094, 'AERL_A', 8.47164154052734
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Dec/2013 23:41:58] "POST /myroute/ HTTP/1.1" 200 152
{'GRSIZE': 'a', 'APSPAC': '6', 'INCORP': 0, 'ORCFLG': 'a', 'KOC': '2', 'METHAP': '6', 'SOL': '3', 'YLOCEN': '12', 'FOTHAP'
 'AIRFLG': 'a', 'APPRAT': '4', 'METHOD': 'a', 'WETTED': 'Yes'}
(530.4227294921875, 448.1323547363281, 198.46009826660156, 74.41312408447266, 49.63011932373047, 'AERL_A', 8.4716415405273
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Dec/2013 23:42:04] "POST /myroute/ HTTP/1.1" 200 153
```

Comment: i don't know what you expect and what you are getting instead...

Comment: What does `geneec2` do?  Do you expect it to return the same results every time?  Does it modify any local or global state?

Comment: Btw, use `return {'ff': ff}`. No need to create json explicitly.

Comment: Also, you might be able to replace all those assignments with something very simple instead, like `geneec2(**request.json)`

Comment: @DonQuestion: I am expecting the same output no matter how many times the page is refreshed given the same set of inputs.

Comment: @ron.rothman `geneec2` was a FORTRAN program compiled as a Python module. Yes, I expect same return for a fixed set of inputs.

Comment: @ron.rothman: Could you be more specific about `geneec2(**request.json)`? Is this something like keyword argument? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt this is related to the REST call itself, since you are getting the same inputs printed out. I would look into what geneec2 is doing itself. You could test the REST call out with all of the parameters set to default values (and not the request information) and then see if this fixes anything. If that doesn't produce consistent results then you will need to recompile geneec2 with a bunch of print statements and see if that gives you a better idea of what is going wrong.